# Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/jbt/jbt.907.tmp': No such file or directory?

Tags: android, android-ndk

My programe runs but i get the above mentioned eroor in logcat what is the reason i could not no getting so help me in this regard. I am providing my stack trace. If any body knows why this error comes please let me know

```
10-26 06:55:55.248: W/System.err(981):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3814)
10-26 06:55:55.248: W/System.err(981):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-26 06:55:55.248: W/System.err(981):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
10-26 06:55:55.248: W/System.err(981):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
10-26 06:55:55.248: W/System.err(981):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:659)
10-26 06:55:55.248: W/System.err(981):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-26 06:55:55.248: W/System.err(981): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-26 06:55:55.248: W/System.err(981):  at com.simsys.securex.PolicyReceiver.onReceive(PolicyReceiver.java:821)
10-26 06:55:55.248: W/System.err(981):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1888)
10-26 06:55:55.248: W/System.err(981):  ... 10 more
10-26 06:56:05.529: I/dalvikvm(981): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
10-26 06:56:05.529: D/dalvikvm(981): SigQuit + : 0
10-26 06:56:05.533: I/dalvikvm(981): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-26 06:56:05.543: E/dalvikvm(981): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/jbt/jbt.981.tmp': No such file or directory
10-26 06:56:05.543: D/dalvikvm(981): SigQuit - : 0
10-26 06:59:19.745: I/dalvikvm(1043): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
10-26 06:59:19.745: D/dalvikvm(1043): SigQuit + : 0
10-26 06:59:19.757: I/dalvikvm(1043): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-26 06:59:19.765: E/dalvikvm(1043): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/jbt/jbt.1043.tmp': No such file or directory
10-26 06:59:19.765: D/dalvikvm(1043): SigQuit - : 0
10-26 06:59:32.834: D/AndroidRuntime(1135): Shutting down VM
10-26 06:59:32.834: W/dalvikvm(1135): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001c648)
10-26 06:59:32.838: W/System.err(1135): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.simsys.securex.PolicyReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-26 06:59:32.839: W/System.err(1135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1899)
10-26 06:59:32.839: W/System.err(1135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:155)
10-26 06:59:32.839: W/System.err(1135):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1043)
10-26 06:59:32.839: W/System.err(1135):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
10-26 06:59:32.840: W/System.err(1135):     at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
10-26 06:59:32.840: W/System.err(1135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3814)
10-26 06:59:32.840: W/System.err(1135):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-26 06:59:32.840: W/System.err(1135):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
10-26 06:59:32.840: W/System.err(1135):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
10-26 06:59:32.841: W/System.err(1135):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:659)
10-26 06:59:32.841: W/System.err(1135):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-26 06:59:32.841: W/System.err(1135): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-26 06:59:32.841: W/System.err(1135):     at com.simsys.securex.PolicyReceiver.onReceive(PolicyReceiver.java:821)
10-26 06:59:32.841: W/System.err(1135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1888)
10-26 06:59:32.842: W/System.err(1135):     ... 10 more
10-26 06:59:43.649: I/dalvikvm(1135): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
10-26 06:59:43.649: D/dalvikvm(1135): SigQuit + : 0
10-26 06:59:43.653: I/dalvikvm(1135): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-26 06:59:43.664: E/dalvikvm(1135): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/jbt/jbt.1135.tmp': No such file or directory
10-26 06:59:43.664: D/dalvikvm(1135): SigQuit - : 0
10-26 07:01:01.606: I/dalvikvm(1184): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
10-26 07:01:01.606: D/dalvikvm(1184): SigQuit + : 0
10-26 07:01:01.611: I/dalvikvm(1184): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-26 07:01:01.613: E/dalvikvm(1184): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/jbt/jbt.1184.tmp': No such file or directory
10-26 07:01:01.613: D/dalvikvm(1184): SigQuit - : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an attempt to access some **null** object at line 821 of your PolicyReceiver.java file.

Regarding the `Unable to open stack trace file` error messages, they seem to be a common problem of some Android system builds. The system tries but fails to write some information that could help you debug your actual bug. This is not relevant for you because you already have this information in the log you see with logcat.